# How to make a specific selectItem of p:selectOneMenu required?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{selectOneMenuView.console}" style="width:125px">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <c:if test="${javaMB.pageTypeId eq 1}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />                                              
                </c:if>             
                <c:if test="${javaMB.pageTypeId eq 2}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS4" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sega" itemValue="Sega" />                          
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${javaMB.pageTypeId eq 3}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii" itemValue="Wii" />                                                
                </c:if>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

How to make the selectItem in a selectOneMenu required?

If a user goes to the page 2  then I need to make the value of Sega required ?

I tried

```
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sega" itemValue="Sega" required="true"/>
```

also  I tried

```
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sega" itemValue="Sega" required="javaMB.write"/>
```

This item is mandatory for the user to select for the condition "javaMB.write"  if he uses page2

I do not need to make the entire p:selectOneMenu  required.

Comment: Hmm im not sure how to make it required from the xhtml, but you can validate if it is null or default or none selected on your managedbean and send a message that points out it is required no?

Comment: Why don't you build the select itemlist in a bean? You don't need the `<c:if` and can do whatever you want.

Comment: What a strange UI requirement. Why don't you just alter the logic so that there is only one selectable item? I.e. no "Select one", no "Xbox", no "PS4", no "Wii" but only "Sega". Or, preset the value and then disable the input component.

Answer (score 0):

When validation of input field depends on some custom and complex conditions (very unusual indeed in your case), one of the solutions would be to define custom [FacesValidator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/validator/FacesValidator.html) for input field (while passing additional values as component `f:attribute`) and implement your own validation rules.

**xhtml example**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:messages id="messages"/>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{javaMB.console}" 
                     validator="customValidator">

        <f:attribute name="pageTypeId" value="#{javaMB.pageTypeId}" />

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <c:if test="${javaMB.pageTypeId eq 1}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />                                              
        </c:if>             
        <c:if test="${javaMB.pageTypeId eq 2}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS4" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sega" itemValue="Sega" />                          
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${javaMB.pageTypeId eq 3}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii" itemValue="Wii" />                                                
        </c:if>
    </p:selectOneMenu>  

    <p:commandButton  value="Submit" process="@form" update=":form:messages"/>

</h:form>
```

**Custom Faces validator**

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator(value = "customValidator")
public class CustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        //get input field value
        String consoleName = (String) value;

        //get some other value passed as component's attribute
        int pageTypeId = (Integer) component.getAttributes().get("pageTypeId");

        System.out.printf("Page type: %d, Console: %s\n", pageTypeId, consoleName);

        //if input is required (not null) for page 2, check if input is null
        if (pageTypeId == 2 && consoleName == null) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Input is required", ""));
        }

        //then implement any logic based on your requirements. For your unusual case,
        if (pageTypeId == 2) {
            if (!consoleName.equals("Sega")) {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Sega is required for page type 2", ""));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note** that your requirements are very unusual from engineering point of view (as others commented too) and that there might be other ways to solve it in UI.

On the other hand, to be honest, once I had similar requirement: some legal team insisted that all "drop down" options are always listed and that user is explicitly informed if "incorrect/not allowed" option is selected. It was so strange to me from engineering point of view but I guess it made some sense from legal point of view.